# how to create clear entry text in tkinter and display on to the window

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm having trouble with finishing a program and I need some help with. I have to clear the Entry text area so that I can retype from the start when I click the "save" button. Also, it would be great if someone could help me with a way to display the Entry text data into the window display if that is possible, but right now, I mainly need to figure out how to clear the entry text area.
Here's the current program, its looks awful but it works.
Also, is it possible to create a function definition to make the window clear if the script is done? Thanks

```py
from tkinter import *

#this function will save the data from tkinter to .txt file.

    def save_data():
        fileD = open("names.txt", "a")
        fileD.write("Name_List:\n")
        fileD.write("%s\n" % name.get())




    #this section will create GUI widget window containing lable, Entry and buttons here.
    app = Tk()
    app.title('Name Library')
    Label(app, text = "Please Enter Name Here:", fg="black").pack()
    name = Entry(app)
    name.pack()
    Label(app, text="New Name will Display Here if Name Changed: ", fg="gold").pack()
    Button(app, text = "Save", fg="red", command = save_data).pack()
    app.configure(background="green")
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clear your entry just use `.delete(0, END)`

```
name = Entry(root)
name.delete(0, END) # clear the entry field
```

For entry widgets the first character starts at `0`. You can use `'end'` or `END` to delete up to the last character of the entry widget or use a set value as well.

Look towards this [guide](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/) for your tkinter neeeds.

Example Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import os

def save_data():
    text = name.get().strip()
    if text: # checks for empty entries
        f = open('names.txt', 'a')
        f.write(text + '\n')
        f.close()
        name.delete(0, tk.END)

# Checks if the file exists
# if not then create it and
# write the header 'Name List'
if not os.path.exists('names.txt'):
    f = open('names.txt', 'w')
    f.write('Name_List:\n')
    f.close()

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Label(root, text = "Please Enter Name Here:").pack()

name = tk.Entry(root)
name.pack()

tk.Button(root, text = 'Save', command = save_data).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: yeah, actually i know that, but for some  reason, when i do that, from the txt file I added a Name List in the text, so every time I clicked the save button, Name List appears every time it is clicked. or i should remove just fileD.write("Name_List:\n") this?

Comment: Your issue is that each times you save you are writing `'Name_List:'` instead of having it only occur once at the top. Your better off creating the file with that line and then add each name on save. Example code provided.